# Regex for capturing different date formats

Tags: regex, date

I'm tasked to capture date for itineraries in email message, but the dates given were all in different formats, I guess I need help to find out if there's any way to capture the following formats:

```
02 APR
APR 02
2 APR
APR 2
2nd APR
APR 2nd
2nd April
April 2nd
APR 12th
April 12th
12th April
April 13-16
13-16 April
APR 13-16
13-16 APR
April 13th-16th
13th-16th April
APR 13th-16th
13th-16th APR
```

I've tried numerous ways but just could not understand or fathom as I'm a 
newbie to regex.

The closest I could get was using this:

```
(\d*)-(\d*) APR|April \d*\d*
```

EDIT- Found out that i`ve missed some more formats.

13th - 16th APR

13~16 April

13/16 APR

I`ve tried using the following:

```
(Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dec(?:ember)?)\ *\d+(?:[nr]d|th|st)?(?: * \d+(?:[nr]d|th|st)?)?|\d+(?:[nr]d|th|st)?(?: . \d+(?:[nr]d|th|st)?)?\ *(?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dec(?:ember)?)
```

Could either capture dates with space or without space.
Is there a way to capture all formats, and split the dates with '-', '/','~' and output/write into a single standardize format?

```
(Group 1 Date)-Month (Group 2 Date)-Month eg: 13-Apr 16-Apr
```

Appreciate for your kind suggestions and comments.

Comment: `\d*\d*` is strictly equivalent to `\d*`

Comment: Anything with `*` can and will match the empty string.  You want `\d+` and you want to make many elements optional. Try something like `(\d+)(?th)?(?:-(\d+)(th)?)? (apr)(?:il)?` for a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with this Regex:

```regex
(?:APR|April)\ *\d+(?:[nr]d|th|st)?(?:-\d+(?:[nr]d|th|st)?)?|\d+(?:[nr]d|th|st)?(?:-\d+(?:[nr]d|th|st)?)?\ *(?:APR|April)
```

See details here: [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/wB9fN2/9)

---

Maybe it's overkill, but I came up with this regex that will match with any month:

```regex
(?:January|JAN|February|FEB|March|MAR|April|APR|May|MAY|June|JUN|July|JUL|August|AUG|September|SEP|October|OCT|November|NOV|December|DEC)\ *\d+(?:[nr]d|th|st)?(?:-\d+(?:[nr]d|th|st)?)?|\d+(?:[nr]d|th|st)?(?:-\d+(?:[nr]d|th|st)?)?\ *(?:January|JAN|February|FEB|March|MAR|April|APR|May|MAY|June|JUN|July|JUL|August|AUG|September|SEP|October|OCT|November|NOV|December|DEC)
```

Unreadable, check here if you want details: [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/wB9fN2/8)

---

Improved version using Wiktor Stribiżew's trick:

```regex
(?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dec(?:ember)?)\ *\d+(?:[nr]d|th|st)?(?:-\d+(?:[nr]d|th|st)?)?|\d+(?:[nr]d|th|st)?(?:-\d+(?:[nr]d|th|st)?)?\ *(?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dec(?:ember)?)
```

See details here: [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kB3gC1/3)
It matches every monthes, it uses less steps (more efficient)
**BUT**, you need to make sure you're **case insensitive**

Comment: You saved me much more time with your overkill expression! Thanks Adrien!

Comment: I'm not english native, maybe you should consider checking the spelling of every months, haha.

Comment: Its all correct, thanks. Can i replace the '-' in between 13-16 with a wildcard '*' so as to capture anything like 13~16 or 13/16?

Comment: I would recommand using a set of known characters instead with something like `[-~ /]` (add characters at your will and don't forget to escape what needs to be escaped)

Comment: You do not need the outer capturing brackets: the whole match is always put into Group 0 and can usually be retrieved easily.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I thougth that downvoting wasn't appropriate for wrong capture... I didn't downvote you btw, I upvoted you for using your answer and because I though the idea was brilliant...

Comment: All I suggest is removing the outer brackets. I hope you understand the *matching* and *capturing* now :) Please do not trust what regex101 shows blindly - it shows capture groups 1+ on the right. Matches are still "captured".

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew So, in your opinion, it's a reason to downvote + vote for deleting the post?? "removing the outer brackets" is done.

Comment: @AdrienBrunelat: It could, I am very touchy but I always fix myself after a couple of minutes. Sorry.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ok, no prob, appreciate the self-control that is quite rare nowadays. I learned about the idea of letting OP deciding what to match and I know reming about the retrieve the full match thing, thanks.

Comment: @user6141713 check out the last edits if you need to spot `1st`

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, Thomas and Adrien!

Answer (score 2):

You need to account for optional values. Here is an enhanced version matching your sample input:

```
/(\d+)(?:st|[nr]d|th)?-?(\d*)(?:st|[nr]d|th)?\s*Apr(?:il)?|Apr(?:il)?\s*(\d+)(?:st|[nr]d|th)?-?(\d*)(?:st|[nr]d|th)?/i
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jI5tY0/1) (**note you need to use a case-insensitive modifier to match any variants of `April`**)

Basically, there are 2 alternatives matching `April` and date ranges:

- `(\d+)(?:st|[nr]d|th)?-?(\d*)(?:st|[nr]d|th)?\s*Apr(?:il)?` - 1+ digits followed with an optional `st`, `nd`, `rd`, `th`, followed with an optional hyphen, followed with 0+ digits, followed with optional `st`, etc. followed with 0+ whitespace and then `Apr` or `April` (case insensitive due to `/i` modifier)
- `|`  - or
- `Apr(?:il)?\s*(\d+)(?:st|[nr]d|th)?-?(\d*)(?:st|[nr]d|th)?` - the same as above  but swapped.

Comment: Yes, with regex, it is always a good idea to avoid alternative groups that can match the same characters at the start to reduce redundant backtracking. Optional groups work wonders in these cases.

Comment: Nice trick, but it seems like your regex isn't capturing the dates, just matching the input.

Comment: @AdrienBrunelat: You do not understand how regex works by saying *isn't capturing the dates, just matching the input*. Matching is always *capturing into Group 0*. It depends on the language if we have to use an outer capturing group enclosing the whole pattern. In older versions of Perl  it is a very good idea, and only there.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this:

```
(\d+(?:th|st|[nr]d)?(?:-\d+(?:th|st|[nr]d)?)?\s*(?:APR|April))|((?:APR|April)\s*\d+(?:th|st|[nr]d)?(?:-\d+(?:th|st|[nr]d)?)?)
```

<kbd>[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eK4pQ8/1)</kbd>