# Regex to capture timestamp in different formats

Tags: .net, regex, replace, nintex-workflow

I have different time formats that come into my report. I’m trying to standardize the format. The two I have seen so far is as follows.

```
3. When: 150845Z - 161045Z Jan 16
When: 15 08:45Z - 16 10:45Z Jan 16
```

My goal is to transform that data from the above input into the following

```
Start date and time 01/15/2016 08:45
End date and time 01/16/2016 10:45
```

I have multiple capture groups and splits to make this happen and to be hones it is rather large and I think it can be simplified.

I can post each step of code I have however it would really bloat this post. 
For the start date and time I do the following

```
(?s)(?<=^.When:\s)[a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

For the end date and time I do the following

```
When:.+(?<=- )(\w.*)
```

I would really like to reduce this as much as possible. I tried to implement this method [Regex for capturing different date formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36689681/regex-for-capturing-different-date-formats) however I'm really new to Regex and piece items together until I get it to work.

Thanks

Additional Information

I'm currently bound to using Nintex Workflows to transform the data. I would like to start the capture after `When:\s` then I can use `[, :]` to remove the remaining spaces and colons. This would leave the data in a format I can manipulate.

Comment: Your [first regex](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3fs)(%3f%3c%3d%5e.When%3a%5cs)%5ba-zA-Z0-9%5d%2b&i=3.+When%3a+150845Z+-+161045Z+Jan+16%0d%0aWhen%3a+15+08%3a45Z+-+16+10%3a45Z+Jan+16) does not work - what do you intend to match? The second one just gets the part after `-`: couldn't you just split the string? Shouldn't you really just search for `When:`, get the substring after it and split with `" - "` to get the parts you need?

Comment: That is what I'm doing now however it is not working quite right. My goal is to have the following captures. `Month, Start Date, End Date, Year, Start Time, End Time`. I'm just not sure how to split the data.

Comment: See [this IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/uBqU6K) first. Is it splitting OK? If not, what exact output do you want to obtain? Then, check this [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e(%3f%3a%5cd%2b%5c.%5cs*)%3fWhen%3a%5cs*(%5cd%7b2%7d)%5cs*(%5cd%7b2%7d)%3a%3f(%5cd%7b2%7dZ)%5cs*-%5cs*(.*)&i=3.+When%3a+150845Z+-+161045Z+Jan+16%0d%0aWhen%3a+15+08%3a45Z+-+16+10%3a45Z+Jan+16&o=m). Is it any better?

Comment: Looking at the regex demo that you provided. It gave me an idea. is it possible to capture everything starting after `When:` then remove all spaces and colons? that would format the data in a way that I could work with.

Comment: See [this demo](http://ideone.com/Cd9nvf) - no regex is required.

Comment: The problem is I'm using Nintex Workflows. The only action I have is RegEx. What I have right now is `[, :]` for the Pattern with `replace` selected and the replacement text is `empty`. What I need to do is start the capture after `When:\s`

Comment: Good, but that should be part of the question - add those details.

Comment: Try [`^.*?When:\s*(\d{2})\s*(\d{2}):?(\d{2}Z)\s*-\s*(\d{2})\s*(\d{2}):?(\d{2}Z)\s*(\w+)\s*(\d{1,2})$`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e.*%3fWhen%3a%5cs*(%5cd%7b2%7d)%5cs*(%5cd%7b2%7d)%3a%3f(%5cd%7b2%7dZ)%5cs*-%5cs*(%5cd%7b2%7d)%5cs*(%5cd%7b2%7d)%3a%3f(%5cd%7b2%7dZ)%5cs*(%5cw%2b)%5cs*(%5cd%7b1%2c2%7d)%5cr%3f%24&i=3.+When%3a+150845Z+-+161045Z+Jan+16%0d%0aWhen%3a+15+08%3a45Z+-+16+10%3a45Z+Jan+16&r=%241%242%243%244%245%246%247%248&o=m)  and replace with `$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8`

Comment: This worked exactly. Thank how do I mark this comment as the answer correct?

Comment: I posted the answer, please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^.*?When:\s*(\d{2})\s*(\d{2}):?(\d{2}Z)\s*-\s*(\d{2})\s*(\d{2}):?(\d{2}Z)\s*(\‌​w+)\s*(\d{1,2})$
```

And replace with `$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8`.

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E.%2A%3FWhen%3A%5Cs%2A(%5Cd%7B2%7D)%5Cs%2A(%5Cd%7B2%7D)%3A%3F(%5Cd%7B2%7DZ)%5Cs%2A-%5Cs%2A(%5Cd%7B2%7D)%5Cs%2A(%5Cd%7B2%7D)%3A%3F(%5Cd%7B2%7DZ)%5Cs%2A(%5Cw%2B)%5Cs%2A(%5Cd%7B1%2C2%7D)%5Cr%3F%24&i=3.%20When%3A%20150845Z%20-%20161045Z%20Jan%2016%0D%0AWhen%3A%2015%2008%3A45Z%20-%2016%2010%3A45Z%20Jan%2016&r=%241%242%243%244%245%246%247%248&o=m)

The point is to match and capture what we need and reinsert these captured texts with the help of backreferences (`$n`s) in the replacement pattern, and those parts we just match will be removed from the resulting string.

Here are some more details for you to be able to adjust the pattern later:

- `^` - start of string/line (no idea if the tool allows matching across lines)
- `.*?` - match 0+ characters other than a newline as few as possible up to the first
- `When:` - literal string `When:`
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespace symbols
- `(\d{2})` - 2 digits (Group 1)
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespace symbols
- `(\d{2})` - 2 digits (Group 2)
- `:?` - optional `:`
- `(\d{2}Z)`  - 2 digits + `Z` (Group 3)
- `\s*-\s*` - 0+ whitepsaces, literal `-` and 0+ whitespace
- `(\d{2})\s*(\d{2}):?(\d{2}Z)\s*` - see above (Group 4, 5, 6)
- `(\‌​w+)` - 1+ word characters (letters, digits, or underscore) (Group 7)
- `\s*` -  0+ whitepsaces
- `(\d{1,2})` - 1 or 2 digits (Group 8)
- `$` - end of string